# Prevent second Func executing when two Funcs have been concatenated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Let's take the example below:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        RequestDelegate a = async (ctx) =>
        {
            if (1 == 1)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("I'm done");
                return;
            }
        };
        RequestDelegate b = async (ctx) => await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Please don't hit this"); ;

        RequestDelegate c = a += b;

        app.Run(c);
    }
```

As the two funcs have been concatenated with the `c` variable both will be executed.  What I'm looking at trying to do is signal in the first func that I don't want the second func to be executed and it should return the HttpResponse as it is in the first func.

Obviously in this simple example I could use a global boolean etc but that's not what I'm getting at, it's really if you have 2 funcs concatenated maybe from 2 separate libs is there a way to make the 2nd func not execute when you have no control over the execution, all you know is that the funcs will be executed by something else you have no control over.

Comment: Are you saying both `a` and `b` are in external libraries and can not be modified, but you do in fact have control over `c`?

Comment: Are you asking that b not be executed if a was first called?

Comment: If `a` throws an exception, `b` will not execute.

Comment: @hometoast no, for `b` to be not executed based on a boolean or a return value from `a`

Comment: @TravisJ yup but not elegant. I wonder if the http request can be cancelled on the first func somehow. I see there is a HTTPContext.RequestAborted but can't see a way to signal it to be cancelled

Comment: Do you have access to `c`?

Comment: Yes but only in the sense that I'm telling asp.net core that this is the func(handler) I want you to execute so when it does execute a not sure how i tell it not to do b